# 32 bit GPU and 64 bit CPU OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I have created my OpenCL code in a dll which I am loading in my application.
Now for my 64 bit application it is crashing for the call getPlatformIds().
However Dependency Walker is showing everything is 64 bit and no errors.
But the same application with 32 bit is working perfectly.
Is it possible that my GPU cannot perform 64 bit tasks?
But C:/Windows/System32/OpenCL.dll is also 64 bit so probably my hardware is ok?

How do I determine what might be causing the crash?

Comment: How is it crashing? Is there an exception being thrown, or an error code returned from an OpenCL function? We'll need to know these before we can help.

Comment: Its a segmentation fault, so I am not getting any error code.

Comment: Your GPU 'bitness' has nothing to do with this. For some reason you are probably calling 32bit code or whichever OpenCL implementation you are using is simply broken.

Comment: Although I am using OpenCL 1.1 headers since my GPU has drivers for 1.1 version only, can the crash be because I am using APP SDK v2.9 which is OpenCL 1.2? But then why would it crash only for 64 bit?

Comment: I found the solution to this generic problem... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Husshhhh....
The issue is finally resolved...:)

Looks like there is some linker problem with the MinGW 64 bit compiler.
The solution is to link the **libopencl.a** file instead of **OpenCL.dll** for building 64 bit applications.

While building for 32 bit applications does not require this i.e. you can link with OpenCL.dll.

Now only if somebody can fix [this issue which has been open for past 4 years](http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1164914)!